What is wrong with this mesh?


As I move the edge closer to the X axis, the mesh appears to have a bad topology. How can I identiify the issue and fix it?. The expected behavior is to have this mesh look like a Z

Looks like you might have doubled verts or overlapping faces, or non-manifold edges. Can't tell without seeing the model itself. I would run through the gamut of Merge by Distance, Select > All by Trait > Non-Manifold/Loose Geo etc > Delete, and so on before doing anything else.

So I think it might be because I manually added edges between vertices using "New Edge/Face from vertices" instead of "Connect vertex paths". Do you think that could be it?

Yeah, New Edge/Face from verts is like pressing "F", while Connect vertex paths will try to find the shortest distance between the two verts on the same mesh and add verts/edges that cut through and connect them together.

Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "this","issue with" or "question about". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See "What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
